# Use different value if another resource is created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I have a Terraform module that I would like to modify.  Currently my module creates a service account.  I would like to modify it so that someone could pass in an existing service account OR if one is not passed in, then the module creates a service account is it would have originally.

Originally my service account looked like this:

```
resource "google_service_account" "scheduler" {
  account_id = "${var.prefix}-scheduler"
  project    = var.project
}
```

I've added the following variable to my `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "service_account_email" {
  default = null
  description = "Existing service account for running ... jobs.  If null a new service account will be created."
}
```

What I originally thought to do was to add some locals

```
locals {
  service_account_count = var.service_account_email == null ? 1 : 0
  service_account_email = var.service_account_email == null ? google_service_account.scheduler.email : var.service_account_email
}
```

Then I could change my service account to look like

```
resource "google_service_account" "scheduler" {
  count = local.service_account_count
  account_id = "${var.prefix}-scheduler"
  project    = var.project
}
```

And then wherever I would have referenced `google_service_account.scheduler.email` I can instead reference `local.service_account_email` ..  It doesn't look like I'm able to do this, however, for a few reasons.

I get the following error if I try to use the locals block that mentioned above:

```
│ Because google_service_account.scheduler has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ F`or example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     google_service_account.scheduler[count.index]
╵
```

If I change it so that I'm using `google_service_account.scheduler[count.index].email` instead, I get the following error:

```
│ Because google_service_account.scheduler has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     google_service_account.scheduler[count.index]
╵
```

Now I'm sort of stuck, because I can't force any resources that would originally have referenced `google_service_account.scheduler.email` to instead reference the `var.service_account_email` variable that is being passed in for cases where we would prefer to use an existing service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `count`, you have to use `[0]` to access your resource:

```
service_account_email = var.service_account_email == null ? google_service_account.scheduler[0].email : var.service_account_email
```